# TKinter OptionMenu background not colouring its border

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to change the background colour of an optionMenu to match my frame's background colour, but there seems to be a border around the OptionMenu that refuses to change and stays white:

[image]

Code for the OptionMenu:

```
export_option=OptionMenu(adv_frame,export_type,'Whole database','Only selected')
export_option.config(width=14,bg='grey80')
export_option.grid(row=1,column=4,sticky='w')
```

Code for the frame:

```
adv_frame=Frame(top_frame,pady=10,padx=3,bg='grey80')
adv_frame.grid(row=3,columnspan=4,sticky='ew')
```

How do i make the white border grey like everything else? I've gone through the menu config options, but couldn't see anything relevant.

Comment: Set the `highlightbackground` to `grey80` as well.

Comment: Thanks, you should have posted this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set highlighttickness:

```
export_option["highlightthickness"] = 0
```

This will remove the border, and you will have unified frame.